# Help with SharePoint List

Tags: list, column, formula

I'm stuck here with this SharePoint List columns formula.
Probably there is a easier way of doing this.
I have a column with two choices, one for phone and other for laptop.

I created the columns but it substract same value 1-10=9.
I would like when select phone it substract -1 from the value of the Available phones column ex.10.And so on everytime is added a new row until it reach zero available.
And when delete the rows it comes back to the default value ex.10.
The same for the laptop choice of course.
I'm gratefull for some advice!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'count related' lookup column to get close to what you need

to do this, you'll need to split in to two lists: one called 'devices' and on called 'reservations'

Now, create a lookup from reservations to device, so that when you make a reservation you can select a device.

Next, make a lookup from the device list to the reservations list. Make sure to select the 'count related' checkbox when creating the column.

This should give you the number of reservations for each device.